# Searching a variable pattern using Python

Tags: python, html, regex

How do I find out the variable pattern from the following HTML code?

```
<element aria-label="like this video along with 3,358,980 other people" >...<element>
```

I want to find the number from the above line.

Comment: html code?????/ I don't find any tags on that..

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I guess, extracted from some `input` element.

Comment: This has been asked a thousand times, where can we see some of your efforts? Remember: this is not a site to dump your todo-list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I think you want a simple regex. Just look for a string of numbers and optionally commas:

```
>>> s='aria-label="like this video along with **3,358,980** other people"'
>>> print(re.search(r"([\d,]+)", s).group(0))
3,358,980
```

Answer (score 0):

If the line of interest is always "some text **number_of_interest** some more text" then you can just split the string on the double asterisks **.

```
split_string = "this is the number **3,444,333** I need".split('**')
number_of_interest = split_string[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is strictly for whole, non-decimal fractional numbers that have optional
thousand separators.

`\d+(?:,\d{3})*`